# To Do list with JavaScript using localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to make my own To Do list using JavaScript and localStorage. After writing the input and pressing the send button, the item will be added and display on the screen. A delete button will appear next to the item. But when I press the delete button, the console shows up: **Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:21)**.

```js
const inpKey = document.getElementById("inpKey");
const inpValue = document.getElementById("inpValue");
const add = document.getElementById("add");
const items = document.getElementById("items");

add.onclick = function() {
  const key = inpKey.value;
  const value = inpValue.value;
  if (key && value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    location.reload();
  }
};

for (let a = 0; a < localStorage.length; a++) {
  const key = localStorage.key(a);
  const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
  items.innerHTML += `${key}: ${value} <button type='button' onclick='deleteItem(${key})'>Delete</button><br>`;

  function deleteItem(key) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="inpKey" type="text">
<input id="inpValue" type="text">
<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>

<div id="items"></div>
```

Comment: I think you just need quotation marks: `...onclick='deleteItem("${key}")'...` - without them there will be just a code like `...deleteItem(apple)...`, assuming the existence of a variable `apple`

Comment: does it work now? btw. `function deleteItem()` could be outside of that loop

Comment: Yes it works :D

Answer (score 0):

When you load the browser, write the current localstorage data to an array/object however you want to set it up.

Based on the array/object size you'd ID them this way, and when you output them to your page you'd setAttribute("id", "currentcount").

And run a window listener for pointerdown over any of the exit buttons and just check the ID loop through your array/object, delete the item and re-save localstorage.

No code but should help you out, you're close.